# Relative import failure in Python 3

Tags: python

Consider the following example package:

```
example/
├── bar.py
├── foo.py
└── __init__.py
```

`foo.py` contains just one line of code: `from . import bar`.

If I execute `python foo.py` from inside the `example` package root, I get:

`SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you’re running `python foo.py`, `foo.py` is not part of the `example` module. Create `__main__.py` to run the relevant part of `foo.py` (it shouldn’t run any code at the top level, generally), change to the parent directory, and try `python -m example`.

For example, `foo.py`:

```
def hello():
    print('Hello, world!')
```

`__main__.py`:

```
from . import foo

foo.hello()
```

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to work, can you just explain your comment that "it shouldn’t run any code at the top level, generally"?  Are you referring to `foo.py`, and is your meaning that the `foo.py` module should not be running any code when it is just being imported?

Comment: @DunPeal: Yes, exactly.

Comment: more specifically: when you run a file as `python a/b/c.py`, python adds `a/b/` to `sys.path`.  don't _ever_ run anything that's supposed to be part of a module hierarchy by filename.  always sit in the parent directory and run it with `-m`.  (you could use `-m example.foo` here if you really really wanted to, too.)